# Docker - Couldn't create the mpm-accept mutex

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, mutex

My Docker container keeps restarting with the following error:

> ```
> Operation not supported: AH00023: Couldn't create the mpm-accept mutex 
>
> (95)Operation not supported: could not create accept mutex
> ```

And I tried some of the solutions online including `platform: linux/amd64` switching docker restart etc...

[THIS](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-wordpress/issues/316) solution does not work for me.

However I did not manage to edit `httpd.conf` file, the solution offered [HERE](https://serverfault.com/questions/1014620/permission-denied-ah02478-failed-to-create-proxy-mutex) because I cannot access docker image to do that as it keeps restarting.

Does anyone now how to surpass this error? I am on Mac `M1`.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM 242425.a.a.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/app-php:7.4

ARG COMPOSER_TOKEN
ENV COMPOSER_TOKEN=${COMPOSER_TOKEN}
ARG GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN
ENV GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN=${GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN}
ARG ENVIRONMENT=""
ENV ENVIRONMENT=${ENVIRONMENT}

RUN apt-get --yes update && apt-get --yes --no-install-recommends install supervisor

RUN if [ "${ENVIRONMENT}" = "local" ]; \
    then pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug; \
    fi

RUN mkdir /root/.composer
RUN if [ "${ENVIRONMENT}" != "local" ]; \
    then echo "${COMPOSER_TOKEN}" > /root/.composer/auth.json; \
    fi

# Configure Apache
COPY ./config/aws/apache2/breitling.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled

# Move application in the correct folder
COPY . /var/www/html/
COPY ./config/aws/secrets_manager/${ENVIRONMENT}/map.csv /usr/local/etc/secrets-map.csv
COPY ./config/aws/supervisor/messenger-worker.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d

# Fix permissions
RUN setfacl -dR \
    -m u:"www-data":rwX \
    -m g:"www-data":rwX \
    -m u:$(whoami):rwX \
    -m o::rwX \
    /var/www/html/var

RUN setfacl -R \
    -m u:"www-data":rwX \
    -m g:"www-data":rwX \
    -m u:$(whoami):rwX \
    -m o::rwX \
    /var/www/html/var

RUN rm -rf \
    /var/www/html/var/cache/prod \
    /var/www/html/var/cache/test \
    /var/www/html/var/cache/dev \
    > /dev/null 2>&1

RUN mkdir -p \
    /var/www/html/var/cache/prod \
    /var/www/html/var/cache/test \
    /var/www/html/var/cache/dev \
    > /dev/null 2>&1

# Build application
RUN if [ "${ENVIRONMENT}" != "local" ]; \
    then /var/www/html/bin/app_build.sh; \
    fi

# BAWS-392
RUN if [ "${ENVIRONMENT}" != "local" ]; then rm -rf /root/.composer/cache; fi
RUN if [ "${ENVIRONMENT}" != "local" ]; then find /var/www/html/vendor -type d -name .git -delete; fi

ENTRYPOINT /var/www/html/bin/entrypoint.aws.sh
```

Comment: It's a bit difficult to diagnose without seeing your Dockerfile, but you could try changing the CMD to CMD ["sh", "-c", "tail -f /dev/null"] which should keep the container running in order for you to be able to access it in a terminal. You could also append "Mutex posixsem" to the file while creating the Docker image using: RUN echo "Mutex posixsem" >> /path/to/httpd.conf

Comment: Thanks for the replay. Could you maybe tell me how to find the path of my docker httpd.conf file? @Bets

Comment: Also if you could explain a little bit how to perform first suggestion as I am new within docker. @Bets

Comment: I think it would be best if you shared the contents of your Dockerfile (or a stripped-down version if there is anything sensitive in it). According to a quick Google search, the httpd.conf file should be located at /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf, so you can add to your Dockerfile (before the CMD line): RUN echo "Mutex posixsem" >> /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf which would modify the file inside the Docker image. For the first suggestion, you can replace the existing CMD line in the Dockerfile, and in both cases you'll need to rebuild the Docker image.

Comment: If you try the CMD ["sh", "-c", "tail -f /dev/null"] option, you can access the container in a terminal via the Docker Desktop GUI (it should have an "Open In Terminal" button by running containers).

Comment: For the second one I get /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Directory nonexistent on docker-build @Bets

Comment: And for the first suggestion I edited my post and added docker file so you can check as I am not sure what should I replace in the file for first suggestion. And in Docker Desktop I can access terminal because the image keeps restarting and that button is off. :/ Thanks @Bets

Comment: It looks like the configuration file may be stored in a different location, you could try /etc/apache2/apache2.conf or one of the other suggestions here: https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/how-to-find-your-apache-configuration-folder/ 
Otherwise you can run the Docker image using: docker run -i <image_name> bash which will keep it open in the terminal and allow you to see what's going on under the hood (so you can locate the conf file, or run any commands from within the container).

Comment: As for building the image, I'm not able to fetch the base image in order to build it - I'm guessing it's a private repository on AWS or something?

Comment: Yes it is.. :/ Can you maybe offer some solution as ran out of ideas.. ? @Bets

Comment: You've tried adding RUN echo "Mutex posixsem" >> /etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf to the Dockerfile before the ENTRYPOINT line?

Comment: Sorry, the path should probably be /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Answer (score 23):

Thanks to @Bets, the problem was solved with adding the following into Dockerfile:

```
RUN echo "Mutex posixsem" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Comment: Hurrah! Glad to be of service!

Comment: This works for the vscode devcontainer with 
`FROM --platform=linux/amd64 mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/php:0-${VARIANT}`